# TypeError: startfile: filepath should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not list

Tags: python, browser

My error is:

````
  File "D:\script.py", line 53, in <module>
    webbrowser.open(website)
  File "C:\Users\Mitko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\webbrowser.py", line 86, in open
    if browser.open(url, new, autoraise):
  File "C:\Users\Mitko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\webbrowser.py", line 603, in open
    os.startfile(url)
TypeError: startfile: filepath should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not list```
````

So question is simple, how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you please show your code that we people can see and solve your problem

Comment: webbrowser.open('google.com'). That's it.

Answer (score 0):

website can be something like website = "https://google.com" or website = filepath(string). From the error it seems website is assigned to a list.